# Dart get extension from UInt8List

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the package [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) to accept an image from the user. This results in a PickedFile and byte array. Since the image is then uploaded I'm wondering how to guess the mime type from the byte array.

```
PickedFile image =
    await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);
Uint8List data = await image.readAsBytes();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`package:mime`](https://pub.dev/packages/mime) has a [`lookupMimeType`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mime/latest/mime/lookupMimeType.html) function that can infer the MIME type either from a file extension or from magic bytes in the content.  As of writing, it should support detecting content for:

- `application/pdf`
- `application/postscript`
- `image/gif`
- `image/jpeg`
- `image/png`
- `image/tiff`
- `video/mp4`
- `model/gltf-binary`

(See https://github.com/dart-lang/mime/blob/master/lib/src/magic_number.dart for the current list of types it supports out of the box.)

You then can use [`extensionFromMime`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mime/latest/mime/extensionFromMime.html) to obtain a file extension.

Example:

```dart
var data = await image.readAsBytes();
var mime = lookupMimeType('', headerBytes: data);
var extension = extensionFromMime(mime);
```