# Is there a way to check the file type in a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create function where if the file type in the database is jpeg and png, I will push them to another list. Other file that is not jpeg and png will not be included in the list

Comment: Try [`package:mime`](https://pub.dev/packages/mime).

Comment: Also see [Dart get extension from UInt8List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66713893/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [path package](https://pub.dev/packages/path) and `extension` function:

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

final path = '/some/path/file.jpeg';

final ext = p.extension(path); // '.jpeg'
```

now you can do whatever you want based on this extension.

Comment: What if it is from the API?

Comment: you can pass the it too like ``` final ext = p.extension('https://majidhaian.com/something/file.jpg');
  print(ext);  // .jpg  ```