# find the type of file fetched from HTTP URL in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

Today someone ask me a simple question And I thought it might be good to answer that here:

> I want to know the type of content when I get the file with HTTP, How?

For example:

```
http.head(Uri.parse(myUrl)).then(
 (response) {
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     /*
         Now find the content type of myUrl
     */
   }
 },
);
```

Comment: Also see [Dart get extension from UInt8List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66713893/), which might be more reliable than depending on the `content-type` value reported by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, this question is very simple

If you have this question, you can refer to this link and use the [official documents](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

But if you are looking for the answer to this question in StackOverflow, the answer is:

```
http.head(Uri.parse(myUrl)).then(
 (response) {
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.headers['content-type']);
   }
 },
);
```

edit:

Thanks to [jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714115/14871941)
Given that content-type is a value reported from the server, it is not reliable.
An alternative and more reliable way is to use [package:mime](https://pub.dev/packages/mime) and the [lookupMimeType](https://pub.dev/documentation/mime/latest/mime/lookupMimeType.html) function. like this:

```
http.get(Uri.parse(myUrl)).then(
 (response) {
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = response.bodyBytes;
      final mime = lookupMimeType('', headerBytes: data);
      print(mime); // Print type of data
   }
 },
);
```

Comment: What's `value`?

Comment: @Bijan 
Oops, I meant `response.headers`.

Comment: note: mime is not reliable if the type is some extension that is not available in its default extension list like .tflite.