# Package MIME returning wrong extension

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, mime-types, mime, flutter-image-picker

All file images are returning jpeg. How to solve this and get the correct MIME type.

```
Flutter doctor - no issues

Flutter 3.7.7

pubspec.yaml
...
image_picker: ^0.8.7+5
mime: ^1.0.4
...

Future<void> chooseImage() async {
  var chosenImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  if (chosenImage != null) {
    setState(
      () {
        _tempFile = File(chosenImage.path);
      },
    );
  } else {
    // User canceled the picker
  }
}
...
List<int> imageBytes = _tempFile!.readAsBytesSync();
String baseimage = base64Encode(imageBytes);

print(lookupMimeType(baseimage, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]));
...
```

If anyone had the same issue and could provide some insight it would be really appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: `headerBytes` is supposed to consist of the beginning of the file you want to identify.  You're passing a hard-coded byte sequence of `[0xFF, 0xD8]`, so it'll always identify the file as JPEG.  Furthermore, the first argument to `lookupMimeType` is supposed to be the file *name*; passing a base64-encoded string makes no sense.  See [Dart get extension from UInt8List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66713893/) for an example of how to use it.